# Как сохранить состояние CheckBox в RecyclerView созданный с помощью библиотеки BRVAH

Tags: android, recyclerview, recyclerview.adapter

В самой документации библиотеки о сохранении состоянии CheckBox информации не нашел.
В интернете предлагают сохранить состояние через SparseBooleanArray и выгрузить их в методе onBindViewHolder. 
Данная библиотека не использует данный метод(может и использует но в адаптере список строится без данного метода).
Реализацию сохранения позиций и состояния уже сделал. Но в каком месте или в каком методе их выгружать?

```
class ExpandableLabServiceAdapter(data: List<MultiItemEntity>) :
BaseMultiItemQuickAdapter<MultiItemEntity, BaseViewHolder>(data){

private var sparseBooleanArray: SparseBooleanArray = SparseBooleanArray()

init {
    addItemType(TYPE_LEVEL_GROUP, R.layout.item_expandable_group_service)
    addItemType(TYPE_LEVEL_ASSAYS, R.layout.item_expandable_service)
}

override fun convert(helper: BaseViewHolder?, item: MultiItemEntity?) {

    when(helper?.itemViewType){
        TYPE_LEVEL_GROUP -> {

            val group = item as GroupAssaysViewModel
            helper.setText(R.id.group_assays_name, group.name)
            helper.setImageResource(R.id.ic_expand, if(group.isExpanded) R.drawable.ic_next_b else R.drawable.ic_next)

            helper.itemView.setOnClickListener {
                val pos = helper.adapterPosition
                if(group.isExpanded) { collapse(pos) } else { expand(pos)}
            }
        }

        TYPE_LEVEL_ASSAYS -> {

            if(!sparseBooleanArray.get(helper.adapterPosition, true)){
                helper.setChecked(R.id.check_assay, true)
            } else { helper.setChecked(R.id.check_assay, false) }

            val assays = item as AssaysViewModel

            helper.setText(R.id.assay_name, assays.name)
            helper.setText(R.id.assay_price, assays.price.toString())

            helper.setOnCheckedChangeListener(R.id.check_assay, CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener { buttonView, isChecked ->
                val adapterPosition = helper.adapterPosition
                if(!sparseBooleanArray.get(adapterPosition, false)) {
                    helper.setChecked(R.id.check_assay, true)
                    sparseBooleanArray.put(adapterPosition, true)
                } else {
                    helper.setChecked(R.id.check_assay, false)
                    sparseBooleanArray.put(adapterPosition, false)
                }

            })

        }
    }



}

companion object{

    private val TAG = ExpandableLabServiceAdapter::class.java.simpleName

    const val TYPE_LEVEL_GROUP = 0
    const val TYPE_LEVEL_ASSAYS = 1
}
```

}